# How to mount a Google Shared Drive in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am working in Google Colaboratory. Until about a week ago, I was able to mount my shared drive using the following:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

and then read a data file using:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/Team Drives/TestProject/test.csv')
```

About a week ago, after they updated team drives to shared drives, that stopped working. How do I access my shared drive files now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that needed to be done was update "Team Drives" to "Shared drives".

Changing the code to this works:

`data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/Shared drives/TestProject/test.csv')`

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, it looks like the Shared Drive path is `Shareddrives` with no space. So:

```
drive.mount('/content/drive/') 
# /contents/drive/Shareddrive/Foo is now pointing to my Foo shared drive
```

Comment: As of 2023, this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Has this changed? I'm trying to access a shared folder but it's not possible..
My code: 

`from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')

in_path = '/content/drive/Shareddrives/CLIENTS/ACP/_stat/_fake_reports/prite/_data/'
combined_df = pd.read_csv(in_path + '_input/2023_PRITE_SCORED_FOR_FAKE_REPORTS_022023.csv',
                          converters={'PROGRAM_CODE' : str})`

And it doesn't find the file. Any advice?

Comment: Sorry @JuanCarlosSaravia, haven't touched this in a while and no idea if it's changed. Good luck!

Comment: It's ok, I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only simple solution that I found myself and is working like charm:

- Step 1: mount google drive normally:

```py
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount("/content/drive")
```

- Step 2: while saving or fetching data from shared drive:

*a) Writing Data to shared drive*

```py
!cp "//content/drive/Shareddrives/<shared_ drive_name>/my-video.mp4" "my-video.mp4"
```

*b) Reading data from Shared Drive*

```py
!cat /content/drive/Shareddrives/<shared_ drive_name>/example.txt
#or
pd.read_csv("/content/drive/Shareddrives/<shared_ drive_name>/data_example.csv")
```

*Note: If if it did not work try to changing name of share drive without spaces*